# Frameless window not working on linux Ubunthu

Tags: qt, qt4

I am creating a dialog which need frameless window, I used

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint );
```

This works for windows but on linux its not working

BaseClass

```
csGuiDialog::csGuiDialog(QWidget *parent)
: QDialog(parent)
{
 Qt::WindowFlags flags = Qt::Dialog| Qt::FramelessWindowHint;

 QWidget::setWindowFlags(flags);
 setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
}
```

Derived class

```
csGuiOutputSelectionMainWindow::csGuiOutputSelectionMainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: csGuiDialog(parent)
{
 setTitle(QString("Selection Window"));
 setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint );
 this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)");
}
```

Why its not working in Linux

Answer (score 0):

```
QRectF framelessGeom = QRectF(15,10,900,575);
setMask(framelessGeom.toRect());
```

This worked but the shadow effect on right and bottom of widget is gone. This shadow effect is default for all widgets in linux